# IE7 and 8 ignoring max-width set to header element

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I have a `header` element with the following CSS. IE7 and 8 are ignoring the `max-width` property. If I change the `header` to be a `div` then it does work.

```
.header {
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
```

This isnt working:

```
<header class="header">
//stuff
</header>
```

This is working:

```
<div class="header">
//stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `max-width` that's being ignored. It's `header`, which is an HTML 5 element and, therefore, not supported by IE 7 & 8.

Check http://www.caniuse.com for browser compatibility.

Consider [**modernizr.com**](https://modernizr.com/) as a workaround. From the website:

> All web developers come up against differences between browsers and
>   devices. That’s largely due to different feature sets: the latest
>   versions of the popular browsers can do some awesome things which
>   older browsers can’t – but we still have to support the older ones.
>
> Modernizr makes it easy to deliver tiered experiences: make use of the
>   latest and greatest features in browsers which support them, without
>   leaving less fortunate users high and dry.

Answer (score 1):

you can always check this site for browser compatibility - http://caniuse.com/.

The New HTML 5 tags are not supported in IE8, so it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot I needed a javascript polyfill to make HTML5 elements work properly on old IE. The following works or you can use modernizr.

```
<script>
  'article aside footer header nav section time'.replace(/\w+/g,function(n){document.createElement(n)})
</script>
```

Comment: also don't forget that IE8 is officially no longer supported by MS, so you should also be advising users to upgrade if possible.